# MongoDB aggregate complex object without destroying its structure

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, summarization

I have a collection whose content is as follows:

```
[
    {
        date: "01-01-2001",
        hour: 7,
        level2: [
            {
                name: "level2A",
                level3: [
                    {
                        name: "level3A",
                        statistic1: 1,
                        statistic2: 1,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "level3B",
                        statistic1: 2,
                        statistic2: 2,
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "level2B",
                level3: [
                    {
                        name: "level3A",
                        statistic1: 3,
                        statistic2: 3,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "level3B",
                        statistic1: 4,
                        statistic2: 4,
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        date: "01-01-2001",
        hour: 8,
        level2: [
            {
                name: "level2A",
                level3: [
                    {
                        name: "level3A",
                        statistic1: 5,
                        statistic2: 5,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "level3B",
                        statistic1: 6,
                        statistic2: 6,
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "level2B",
                level3: [
                    {
                        name: "level3A",
                        statistic1: 7,
                        statistic2: 7,
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In the first level I have a date, an hour and a collection of level2 elements. I have an element for each hour.

In the second level I have a name and a collection of level3 elements. Notice that the name is unique to the current array, but can be duplicated in an object of a different hour.

In the last level I have a name and some numbers. Notice that the name is unique to the current array, but can be duplicated in an object of a different level2 element.

I need to aggregate the data by date, in a way that the statistic numbers will be summarized by the key: date + level2.name + level3.name, without breaking the structure of my complex object. For my example content I've posted here, I want to get the following result for the input: {date: "01-01-2001"}:

```
[
    {
        date: "01-01-2001",
        hour: null,
        level2: [
            {
                name: "level2A",
                level3: [
                    {
                        name: "level3A",
                        statistic1: 6,
                        statistic2: 6,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "level3B",
                        statistic1: 8,
                        statistic2: 8,
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "level2B",
                level3: [
                    {
                        name: "level3A",
                        statistic1: 10,
                        statistic2: 10,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "level3B",
                        statistic1: 4,
                        statistic2: 4,
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

How can I do that without breaking the structure and then rebuilding it in Node.js code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below. First, unwind all the nested arrays, group & sum level 3 statistics fields and then group & push level 3, and then group & push the level 2 and finally project the fields to the results.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$level2"
}, {
    $unwind: "$level2.level3"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            date: "$date",
            level2: "$level2.name",
            level3: "$level2.level3.name"
        },
        statistic1: {
            $sum: "$level2.level3.statistic1"
        },
        statistic2: {
            $sum: "$level2.level3.statistic2"
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            date: "$_id.date",
            level2: "$_id.level2"
        },
        level3: {
            $push: {
                name: "$_id.level3",
                statistic1: "$statistic1",
                statistic2: "$statistic2"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id.date",
        level2: {
            $push: {
                name: "$_id.level2",
                level3: "$level3"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        date: "$_id",
        level2: "$level2"
    }
}]);
```

Output:

```
{
    "level2": [{
        "name": "level2A",
        "level3": [{
            "name": "level3B",
            "statistic1": 8,
            "statistic2": 8
        }, {
            "name": "level3A",
            "statistic1": 6,
            "statistic2": 6
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "level2B",
        "level3": [{
            "name": "level3B",
            "statistic1": 4,
            "statistic2": 4
        }, {
            "name": "level3A",
            "statistic1": 10,
            "statistic2": 10
        }]
    }],
    "date": "01-01-2001"
}
```